# cairo contract with constructor won't compile

Tags: contract, starknet, cairo-lang

[image: this the screenshot]I have a very simple cairo contract that I want to compile using `scarb build` but it won't compile, below is my code:

```
use serde:: Serde;
use starknet:: ContractAddress;
use array:: ArrayTrait;
use option::OptionTrait;

#[derive(Drop, Serde)]
struct Call{
    to: ContractAddress,
    selector: felt252,
    calldata:Array<felt252>,
}

#[account_contract]
mod Account{
    use starknet::get_caller_address;
    use starknet::get_tx_info;
    use starknet:: call_contract_syscall;
    use starknet:: VALIDATED;
    use array:: ArrayTrait;
    use array::SpanTrait;
    use box::BoxTrait;
    use ecdsa :: check_ecdsa_signature;
    use option::OptionTrait;
    use super:: Call;
    use starknet::ContractAddress;
    use zeroable:: Zeroable;
    use serde::ArraySerde;

    struct Storage {
        fam_code: felt252,
    }
   

    #[constructor]
    fn constructor(_fam_key:felt252){
        fam_code::write(_fam_key);
        return();
    }
}
```

as we don't have much online resource on Cairo, I am hoping to get assistance here

Answer (score 0):

I need more information to reproduce the error.
Can you share the following please?

- Which scarb version you are using?
- What does the error say

Edit:
The issue you are facing is that Scarb 0.4.0 uses a new version of the Cairo compiler, in which the way storage is declared and managed is changed. Please check out [this post](https://community.starknet.io/t/cairo-1-contract-syntax-is-evolving/94794) for more information. Happy hacking!

Comment: Thank you for the response , This is my `scarb version`  and `cairo-lang version` respectively:


`scarb 0.4.0 (f813517bf 2023-06-06)`
`cairo: 1.1.0 (43b83560d)`

Comment: also I added a screenshot detailing the error I got